# Irreducible polynomials and Eisenstein's criterion.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I am looking for a counter-example for the following:

If $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $Z[x]$, then there is a polynomial in $Z[x], q(x)$, so that $p(q(x))$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: You could just take $g(x)=x$. The question asks for one such polynomial.

Comment: I guess that is not what the question is asking for, but if you take $p(x)=l$ for a prime number $l$, this is an irreducible polynomial which doesn't change under precomposition and you cannot strictly speaking apply Eisenstein's criterion to it...

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.